# Extract src from each iframe and insert it into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have different iframes that embed youtube videos or slideshare presentation.
I was able to get src from iframes but I want to show for any iframe a div with the correct src url.
Actually I'm using this code:

```
    $.each($("iframe"), function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', src);  
        console.log(src);
        $(".avia-iframe-wrap").before('<div>' + src + '</div>');
    });
```

Problem is that I get all the src url of the page above any iframe, see the attached image: 
[attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kysrH.jpg)

Basically I need to show only youtube url above youtube iframe and only slideshare url above slideshare iframe. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you include your HTML - to get the exact result will depend on where the iframe is in relation to the iframe-wrap.  You might want .before or you might want .prepend etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("iframe").each(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).find(".avia-iframe-wrap").before('<div>' + src + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: `$(this).find(".avia-iframe-wrap")` where `this` is the iframe is unlikely to work.  Probably want `$(this).before(...` or `$(this).closest(".avia-iframe-wrap)".before...` but will depend on OPs HTML, might even want `.prepend`

Comment: It works like this:

 $("iframe").each(function(){
       var link = $(this).attr("src");
       $(this).closest(".avia-iframe-wrap").before('<div>' + link + '</div>');
   });

Thank you Both Amir Rahman and freedomn-m

Comment: sorry that i didnt answered exactly but somehow you managed your code so thats great .